# YouTube video height is too small in WebView Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-webview, android-jetpack-compose

I am playing around with Jetpack Compose, so I created an sample app that has only one webview that loads the YouTube URL. and When I play a video the height of the video is too small.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Surface {
        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                WebView(context).apply {
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                    webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
                }
            },
            update = {
                it.loadUrl("https://youtube.com")
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a bug, I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128). It's strange that it works fine in XML based app, and doesn't in Compose.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom aspect ratio to your layout by `Modifier.aspectRatio(16 / 9f)` (16:9 is the most common video aspect ratio).

Or if you want to see more content from the `WebView` you can just make the size larger or make it `fillMaxSize()`.

If you actually want to create an app that uses YouTube webviews, I suggest looking at [this library](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) both for code reference and potentially just using it.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem. As pointed by @Pylyp Dukhov, it doesn't happens when using XML. So what I did, for now, is inflate a XML with a WebView inside a Frame layout an pass that as the Android view's factory's return

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I still don't know why it behaves like that (I guess it's a bug) but in the end I got it working by using the [Google Accompanist WebView](https://google.github.io/accompanist/web/).

```
val state = rememberWebViewState("https://youtube.com")

WebView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    state = state
)
```

[Here](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/webview/BasicWebViewSample.kt) is a full example.

---

Edit:

Looking at the Accompanist WebView source code, you only have to set the WebView height and width to MATCH_PARENT. Like this:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        WebView(context).apply {
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            loadUrl("https://youtube.com")
        }
    }
)
```